# Why did celebrate request validation failed?

Tags: node.js, express, joi

I tried to reproduce Adam's example from [medium](https://medium.com/@adambretz/time-to-celebrate-27ccfc656d7f).

```
    const app = express();
app.use(expressLogger);
app.use(BodyParser.json());

app.post('/signup', celebrate({
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    age: Joi.number().integer(),
    role: Joi.string().default('admin')
  }),
  query: {
    token: Joi.string().token().required()
  }
}), (req, res) => {
    logger.debug('Calling res.send');
    res.json({ success: true, data : { name, age, role }});
});
```

This is error

```
 "message": "celebrate request validation failed",
    "validation": {
        "query": {
            "source": "query",
            "keys": [
                "token"
            ],
            "message": "\"token\" is required"

        }
```

Postman POST request

```
{
    'name' : 'John J.',
    'age' : 23,
}
```

I set token as parameters,works fine now.
I got reference error now.

```
<body>
    <pre>ReferenceError: name is not defined<br>
```

This is simple example. This what pino-logger shows

```
err":{"type":"Error","message":"failed with status code 500","stack":"Error: failed with status code 500\n    at ServerResponse.onResFinished (/home/trajche/pract/joi1/node_modules/pino-http/logger.js:73:38)\n    at ServerResponse.emit (events.js:326:22)\n    at onFinish (_http_outgoing.js:751:10)\n    at callback (_stream_writable.js:501:21)\n    at afterWrite (_stream_writable.js:454:5)\n    at afterWriteTick (_stream_writable.js:441:10)\n    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:21)"},"responseTime":3,"msg":"request errored"}
ReferenceError: name is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you try to return the data using `res.json({ success: true, data : { name, age, role }});`, none of the variables `name`, `age` or `role` have been defined. You need to retrived them from the request body first.

Either with

```
res.json({ success: true, data : { name: req.body.name, age: req.body.age, role: req.body.role }});
```

Or perhaps a nicer way

```
const { name, age, role } = req.body;
res.json({ success: true, data : { name, age, role }});
```